# Dumping spam emails to one mailbox for processing using spamassassin and postfix on a mail relay server

Tags: email, postfix, mail-server, spamassassin

Our organization is using postfix on Ubuntu as a mail relay server so there's no official mailboxes on it other than root.  I've noticed some spam in the log which spamassassin caught, but they're false positives (pdf files that are gzipped by a printer / scanner / copier).  We have no incoming emails from anything other than our organization (local network only).

I'd like to set it up so these emails get dumped into either root's mail or a user set up specifically for spam mail so I can teach spamassassin using spam / ham.  And if it's ham, have it sent out properly.

Please let me know what kind of information is further needed.

Thanks!

Comment: **How** have you integraeted postfix (smtp server) and spamassassin?  There is more than one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think most of it was automated by the apt-get install as it was up and running but I did make the modifications to the master.cf file, just to be sure.  I'll put them in separate comments.

Comment: pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
         -o content_filter=spamassassin
         -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks

Comment: spamassassin    unix    -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=R user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

Answer (score 0):

We use postfix content filtering. In my company we have:

smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks (main.cf)

/^X-Spam-Status: Yes/  REDIRECT my_quarantine@mail.thing  (in the file named header_checks)

Of course, you need to enable content filtering on your postfix server. You can use any name you want instead of "header_checks" (this is just an example) and you can create a dummy mail account on your server to store your quarantine (google is your friend)